# Nested json response from many tables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

As of now I can call an API using laravel.

I have 2 different `views` in my database.

I have `view_project_percentage` and `view_projtask`

`view_project_percentage` is a list of project that contains project details.

`view_projtask` is a list of task per project

Like for example.

If I have `3 projects` in my `view_project_percentage`

like

`ProjCode` of `ABC1,ABC2, ABC3`

and In my `view_projtask`

I have

`2 task for ProjectCode ABC1`

`1 task for ProjectCode ABC2`

`3 task for ProjectCode ABC3`

Now what I'm trying to do is to get the json array response like this

```
 [
{
    "id": 9,
    "proj_code": "ZQQKVOTRJJNZ",
    "proj_title": "P12",
    "proj_desc": "Project Description 12",
    "target_man_days": 1000000,
    "issue": 0,
    "report": 1,
    "total_employee": 3,
    "hours_8": "4",
    "hours_6": "0.0",
    "hours_3": "0",
    "total_weight_progress": "5.00",
    "est_start_date": "2020-01-20 09:42:00",
    "est_end_date": "2020-01-20 21:42:00",
    "act_start_date": "2020-01-20 09:42:00",
    "act_end_date": "2020-01-20 21:42:00",
    "longitude": "121.07642460",
    "latitude": "14.56055010",
    "location": "Pasig, Metro Manila, Philippinae",
    "status": null,
    "deleted": 0,
    "by_id": 7,
    "updated_by": "Keigh Dee",
    "created_at": "2020-01-20 09:42:31",
    "updated_at": "2020-01-22 14:01:08",
    {
       "taskCode": "J5X1FHCMVFSQ",
       "total_task_weight": null,
       "taskWeight": "50.00",
       "plan_days": "5",
       "actual_days": "5",
       "task_title": "Task 5",
       "task_desc": "Description 5",
       "taskDeleted": 0,
        "view_projtask_deleted": 0
    },
    {
        "taskCode": "FZPRFIWOKBFQ",
        "total_task_weight": "5.00",
        "taskWeight": "25.00",
        "plan_days": "5",
        "actual_days": "5",
        "task_title": "Task 2",
        "task_desc": "Description 2",
        "taskDeleted": 0,
        "view_projtask_deleted": 0
   }
},

........so on
```

As you can see on my example json response I have

`1 project with 2 tasks`

here's my working code

```
public function get_all_projtask()
{
    $proj_query = "SELECT a.id, a.proj_code, a.proj_title, a.proj_desc, a.target_man_days, a.issue, a.report, a.total_employee, a.hours_8, a.hours_6, a.hours_3,
    a.total_weight_progress, a.est_start_date, a.est_end_date, a.act_start_date, a.act_end_date, a.longitude, a.latitude, a.location, a.status, a.deleted, 
    a.by_id, a.updated_by, a.created_at, a.updated_at, b.taskCode, b.total_task_weight, b.taskWeight, b.plan_days, b.actual_days, b.task_title, b.task_desc, b.taskDeleted, b.deleted as view_projtask_deleted

    FROM `view_projtask` AS b LEFT JOIN `view_project_percentage` AS a ON b.projCode = a.proj_code";

    $proj = DB::connection('mysql')->select($proj_query);

    if(count($proj)){
        return $proj;
    }else{
        return response([
            'status'=>'bad',
            'message'=>'No record found'
            ]);
    }
}
```

My query in here is just getting all the tasks per specific project from `view_projtask`

I'm trying to do a json response that getting all the project list uniquely and inside of that json of project contains multiple tasks

My `view_projtask`

[image]

My `view_project_percentage`

[image]

**update**

This is my current output from api

```
[
{
    "id": 9,
    "proj_code": "ZQQKVOTRJJNZ",
    "proj_title": "P12",
    "proj_desc": "Project Description 12",
    "target_man_days": 1000000,
    "issue": 0,
    "report": 1,
    "total_employee": 3,
    "hours_8": "4",
    "hours_6": "1.0",
    "hours_3": "0",
    "total_weight_progress": "5.00",
    "est_start_date": "2020-01-20 09:42:00",
    "est_end_date": "2020-01-20 21:42:00",
    "act_start_date": "2020-01-20 09:42:00",
    "act_end_date": "2020-01-20 21:42:00",
    "longitude": "121.07642460",
    "latitude": "14.56055010",
    "location": "Pasig, Metro Manila, Philippinae",
    "status": null,
    "deleted": 0,
    "by_id": 7,
    "updated_by": "Keigh Dee",
    "created_at": "2020-01-20 09:42:31",
    "updated_at": "2020-01-22 14:01:08",
    "taskCode": "OKIX19IR1DST",
    "total_task_weight": null,
    "taskWeight": "25.00",
    "plan_days": "5",
    "actual_days": "5",
    "task_title": "Task 1",
    "task_desc": "Description 1",
    "taskDeleted": 0,
    "view_projtask_deleted": 0
},
{
    "id": 9,
    "proj_code": "ZQQKVOTRJJNZ",
    "proj_title": "P12",
    "proj_desc": "Project Description 12",
    "target_man_days": 1000000,
    "issue": 0,
    "report": 1,
    "total_employee": 3,
    "hours_8": "4",
    "hours_6": "1.0",
    "hours_3": "0",
    "total_weight_progress": "5.00",
    "est_start_date": "2020-01-20 09:42:00",
    "est_end_date": "2020-01-20 21:42:00",
    "act_start_date": "2020-01-20 09:42:00",
    "act_end_date": "2020-01-20 21:42:00",
    "longitude": "121.07642460",
    "latitude": "14.56055010",
    "location": "Pasig, Metro Manila, Philippinae",
    "status": null,
    "deleted": 0,
    "by_id": 7,
    "updated_by": "Keigh Dee",
    "created_at": "2020-01-20 09:42:31",
    "updated_at": "2020-01-22 14:01:08",
    "taskCode": "FZPRFIWOKBFQ",
    "total_task_weight": "5.00",
    "taskWeight": "25.00",
    "plan_days": "5",
    "actual_days": "5",
    "task_title": "Task 2",
    "task_desc": "Description 2",
    "taskDeleted": 0,
    "view_projtask_deleted": 0
},
{
    "id": 9,
    "proj_code": "ZQQKVOTRJJNZ",
    "proj_title": "P12",
    "proj_desc": "Project Description 12",
    "target_man_days": 1000000,
    "issue": 0,
    "report": 1,
    "total_employee": 3,
    "hours_8": "4",
    "hours_6": "1.0",
    "hours_3": "0",
    "total_weight_progress": "5.00",
    "est_start_date": "2020-01-20 09:42:00",
    "est_end_date": "2020-01-20 21:42:00",
    "act_start_date": "2020-01-20 09:42:00",
    "act_end_date": "2020-01-20 21:42:00",
    "longitude": "121.07642460",
    "latitude": "14.56055010",
    "location": "Pasig, Metro Manila, Philippinae",
    "status": null,
    "deleted": 0,
    "by_id": 7,
    "updated_by": "Keigh Dee",
    "created_at": "2020-01-20 09:42:31",
    "updated_at": "2020-01-22 14:01:08",
    "taskCode": "J5X1FHCMVFSQ",
    "total_task_weight": null,
    "taskWeight": "50.00",
    "plan_days": "5",
    "actual_days": "5",
    "task_title": "Task 5",
    "task_desc": "Description 5",
    "taskDeleted": 0,
    "view_projtask_deleted": 0
},
{
    "id": 8,
    "proj_code": "SUZ82OJI091M",
    "proj_title": "P1",
    "proj_desc": "Project Description 1",
    "target_man_days": 10000,
    "issue": 0,
    "report": 0,
    "total_employee": 2,
    "hours_8": "1",
    "hours_6": "0.5",
    "hours_3": "0",
    "total_weight_progress": null,
    "est_start_date": "2020-01-20 09:41:00",
    "est_end_date": "2020-01-20 21:41:00",
    "act_start_date": "2020-01-20 09:41:00",
    "act_end_date": "2020-01-20 21:41:00",
    "longitude": "121.07642460",
    "latitude": "14.56055010",
    "location": "Pasig, Metro Manila, Philippinae",
    "status": null,
    "deleted": 0,
    "by_id": 7,
    "updated_by": "Keigh Dee",
    "created_at": "2020-01-20 09:41:29",
    "updated_at": "2020-01-20 09:41:29",
    "taskCode": "J5X1FHCMVFSQ",
    "total_task_weight": null,
    "taskWeight": "50.00",
    "plan_days": "5",
    "actual_days": "5",
    "task_title": "Task 5",
    "task_desc": "Description 5",
    "taskDeleted": 0,
    "view_projtask_deleted": 0
},
```

Comment: Hello,did you consider using Eloquent and Laravel models to fetch your results ? That would make the formatting of your data much easier and neat if so, I recommend it.

Comment: could you give a dummy mysql dump to test the queries on?
Is your query giving appropriate response in phpmyadmin?

Comment: check my updated post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider using eloquent (which you really should) your models for these tables shall look something like:

```
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $table = "view_project_percentage";

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProjectTask::class, 'projCode', 'proj_code');
    }
}

class ProjectTask extends Model
{
    protected $table = "view_projtask";

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class, 'projCode', 'proj_code');
    } 
}
```

Then all you need in your controller:

```
public function get_all_projtask()
{   
    return response()->json(Project::with('tasks')->get());
}
```

Comment: I did this seems too close here's my error occured ` "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'view_projtask.proj_code' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from view_projtask where view_projtask.proj_code in (?))",`

Comment: `proj_code` is a primary key of `view_project_percentage` and `projCode` is a foreign inside of `view_projtask` is there any idea to fix thi s one?

Comment: my mistake, try replace 'proj_code' and 'projCode' in your models. I mean in these relations hasMany/belongsTo
EDIT: ive edited answer

Comment: Can I add a where clause on this? like `WHERE deleted = 0` on the view_projtask?

Comment: yes, check this out https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: Oh you mean "where to projects table", then 
Project::where(['deleted' => 0])->with('tasks')->get()

Comment: I tried this one and it works too `return $this->belongsTo(Project::class, 'proj_code', 'projCode')
        ->where('deleted',0)
        ->where('taskDeleted',0);` thanks man

Comment: Hi thankyou for the answer but is there anyway on how can I filter the response based on `auth()->user()->company_id` ? here's a question link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60086645/json-response-filtered-by-id-from-another-table-in-laravel