# Json response filtered by ID from another table in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

Currently I have this 2 different `views` in my database.

The first one is `view_project_percentage` where all the projects are listed with its details

and `view_projtask` a list of task per specific project

`view_project_percentage`

[image]

`view_projtask`

[image]

and I have this working code

My Models

`Project.php`

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
protected $table = "view_project_percentage";

public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProjectTask::class, 'projCode', 'proj_code')
    ->where('deleted',0);
}
}
```

and

`ProjectTask.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProjectTask extends Model
{
protected $table = "view_projtask";

public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class, 'proj_code', 'projCode')
    ->where('deleted',0)
    ->where('taskDeleted',0);
} 
}
```

and in my `Controller` I have this

```
 public function get_all_projtask()
{
    return response()->json(Project::with('tasks')->get());
}
```

I'm getting all the project list from the codes above with this response

```
 [
{
    "id": 9,
    "proj_code": "ZQQKVOTRJJNZ",
    "proj_title": "P12",
    "proj_desc": "Project Description 12",
    "target_man_days": 1000000,
    "issue": 0,
    "report": 1,
    "total_employee": 3,
    "hours_8": "4",
    "hours_6": "1.0",
    "hours_3": "0",
    "total_weight_progress": "5.00",
    "est_start_date": "2020-01-20 09:42:00",
    "est_end_date": "2020-01-20 21:42:00",
    "act_start_date": "2020-01-20 09:42:00",
    "act_end_date": "2020-01-20 21:42:00",
    "longitude": "121.07642460",
    "latitude": "14.56055010",
    "location": "Pasig, Metro Manila, Philippinae",
    "status": null,
    "deleted": 0,
    "by_id": 7,
    "updated_by": "Keigh Dee",
    "created_at": "2020-01-20 09:42:31",
    "updated_at": "2020-01-22 14:01:08",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": 40,
            "projCode": "ZQQKVOTRJJNZ",
            "taskCode": "OKIX19IR1DST",
            "total_task_weight": null,
            "taskWeight": "25.00",
            "plan_days": "5",
            "actual_days": "5",
            "task_title": "Task 1",
            "task_desc": "Description 1",
            "taskDeleted": 0,
            "deleted": 0,
            "by_id": 79,
            "updated_by": "Super Admin",
            "created_at": "2020-01-22 14:01:08",
            "updated_at": "2020-01-22 14:01:08"
        },
        {
            "id": 41,
            "projCode": "ZQQKVOTRJJNZ",
            "taskCode": "FZPRFIWOKBFQ",
            "total_task_weight": "5.00",
            "taskWeight": "25.00",
            "plan_days": "5",
            "actual_days": "5",
            "task_title": "Task 2",
            "task_desc": "Description 2",
            "taskDeleted": 0,
            "deleted": 0,
            "by_id": 79,
            "updated_by": "Super Admin",
            "created_at": "2020-01-22 14:01:08",
            "updated_at": "2020-01-22 14:01:09"
        },
        {
            "id": 39,
            "projCode": "ZQQKVOTRJJNZ",
            "taskCode": "J5X1FHCMVFSQ",
            "total_task_weight": null,
            "taskWeight": "50.00",
            "plan_days": "5",
            "actual_days": "5",
            "task_title": "Task 5",
            "task_desc": "Description 5",
            "taskDeleted": 0,
            "deleted": 0,
            "by_id": 79,
            "updated_by": "Super Admin",
            "created_at": "2020-01-22 14:01:08",
            "updated_at": "2020-01-22 14:01:08"
        }
    ]
},
 ........and projects more....
```

What I'm trying to do is to filter these projects based on current `auth()->user()->company_id` to filter them. I have this table called `tbl_emp_proj` where all the `projCode` are listed together with `emp_id` which means for every user contains multiple or single project.

This is my table

[image]

I only want to show a response if the project is for user using this `auth()->user()->company_id = emp_id` that the record from `tbl_emp_proj` is `deleted = 0`

`emp_id` is coming from `tbl_emp_proj`

Comment: Not sure if i'm misunderstanding your request, but can't you just add a where('emp_id', auth()->user()->company_id) or something?

Comment: Model for `Project.php` is for `view_project_percentage` and `ProjectTask.php` is for `view_projtask` i don't think I can do that because there is no connection with `tbl_emp_proj` since `emp_id`  is located on that table

Comment: You should add a one-to-many relationship between the emp_id (whatever Model it belongs to) and the Project model. Then, you can add a whereHas() filter to your calls.

Comment: Can u give me an example. I'm very new to this framework still adopting the coding style.

Comment: How is user and tbl_emp_proj  connected?

Comment: `tbl_emp_proj` is a list of projects for specific person. I'm using `emp_id` to identify them which user is under for specific proj using `projCode` now I want to filter using `auth()->user()->company_id` to match with `emp_id`

Comment: so tbl_emp_proj.emp_Id == auth()->user()->company_id ?

Comment: yes like that. `tbl_emp_proj.emp_Id == auth()->user()->company_id  ` and `tbl_emp_proj.deleted == 0` but in my case. I only have 2 views that are connected as of now in my codes. the `view_project_percentage` and `view_projtask` how can I link `tbl_emp_proj` just to filter them

Comment: your naming is so inconsistent with what Laravel expects that it makes this question 10 times harder than it has to. Is there a company table anywhere since you have a company id? and how can emp_id be the same as company_id that makes no logical sense?

Comment: I only have different naming but the value of these fields are the same `emp_id` and `company_id`. I solved this problem by using raw query but I need to do it using eloquent. `auth()->user()->company_id` is a field coming from table `users` which is the primary key of a user and in my `tbl_emp_proj` im using `emp_id` equivalent to `auth()->user()->company_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another model for your employee project

```
<?php

...
class EmployeeProject extends Model
{
protected $table = 'tbl_emp_proj';

public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Project::class, 'projCode');
}
```

In your controller you can filter it using their empployee id and lazy load relationship.

Btw, read more documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

```
public function get_all_projtask()
{
    $useProject = EmployeeProject::where(['emp_id' =>auth()->user()->company_id])-firstOrFail();
    return response()->json($useProject->load('projects.tasks'));
}
```

Comment: Hello, im having a problem like this `"message": "Call to a member function load() on null",`..

Comment: @RaeIan Please check if $userProject has value and i updated my answer for the null checking. kabayan

Comment: thanks man! The code is working, i just logged on the wrong account and using a company id with no record now its working

Comment: Ideally, tho, employee-project relationship would have been a pivot between `Employee` and `Project` models. But fair enough, you can't build that kinda pivot without seeing more of the codebase.